# Variable Declaration with the Presence of Nested Functions

Tags: matlab

Someone on [/r/matlab](http://www.reddit.com/r/matlab/comments/20c9jk/inevitable_flappy_bird_for_matlab/) asked me a really interesting question a few days ago related to a [Flappy Bird clone](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45795-flappy-bird-for-matlab/) submitted to the MATLAB FEX. The poster noticed that if you open the main `.m` file, stop it in the debugger on the first line, and run a `whos()`, you see a bunch of variables before they are explicitly defined by the function.

The first thing that I noticed in the editor was the syntax highlighting indicating the presence of nested functions. At a glance, it seems like the variables returned by the `whos()` are only those that will be defined at some point in the scope of the base function.

You can recreate this with a simpler example:

```
function testcode
asdf = 1;
    function testing
        ghfj = 2;
    end
end
```

If you set a breakpoint on the first line and run a `whos()`, you get

```
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class           Attributes

  ans       0x0                 0  (unassigned)              
  asdf      0x0                 0  (unassigned)
```

I couldn't seem to find anything explaining this behavior in the documentation for nested functions or related topics. I am not a computer scientist and my programming knowledge is limited to MATLAB and a very small sprinkling of Python. Can anybody explain what is going on? Does it have something to do with how MATLAB compiles the code at run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workspace of a function with nested function is protected. When the function is called, Matlab has to analyze the code to determine which variables are in scope at what part of the function. Remember, variables that are declared in the main function and that are used in a nested function are passed by reference, and can be modified within the nested function even if not explicitly declared as input or output.

To avoid messing up any of the nested functions, and possibly to help speed things up, Matlab does not allow assigning any additional variables to the workspace of that function. For example, if you stop the execution of the code at line 1, and then try assigning a value to a new variable `klmn`, Matlab will throw an error. This can be a bit frustrating for debugging, but you can always assign `ans`, fortunately.

Comment: Interesting, thank you! With some more digging I did notice a couple sentences in the [function basics documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/variables-in-nested-and-anonymous-functions.html) about all variables needing to be present in the text of the code. I'd be curious to read more about the reasoning behind using a static workspace, but the search results I've seen just point to questions on this error.